# Remove leading apostrophes when copying numbers in General format with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm tweaking a simple macro to copy a list of numbers contained in an EDD file that are formatted as General; I need to transpose them and paste just the values. Once they're pasted, I need to apply custom formatting to specific ones by selecting them and doing a second macro. The problem is the numbers all get pasted with a leading apostrophe and the custom format won't work on them. (It works on all other numbers on the sheet I've entered manually, and works when I manually go in and remove the apostrophe.)

I can't change the 'general' format to 'number' for each source selection (I'll be using filters to get lists like this dozens of times, so I could but the point of VBA is to not be doing that!)

```
Sub Transpose_Values()
'
' Transpose_Values Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Selection.NumberFormat = 0#
    
End Sub
```

I've tried a bunch of variations of NumberFormat and nothing works. The apostrophes stay. How could I fix this? I'm flipping the "Results' into this table and need to apply any 'Flags' with custom formatting to the numbers like this:
[image]

[image]

(Note the highlighted '9.5' has an apostrophe (came from the transpose macro) and won't accept the key command to add a 'J flag' like the cells in the upper right have, which I entered manually as numbers and the key command works for)

UPDATE: I tried changing the format to 'Number' in a selection of the source data just to see if that worked, and it still pasted all the cells in with apostrophes. Except for the first value, interestingly. Whether it has an '<' or not, it gets pasted in normally and the others all have apostrophes, even when the source data is already set to 'Number'.

Comment: If you are pasting values, please set ranges to each other, don't copy/paste.

Comment: Going to do this across dozens/hundreds of different ranges in different books. Im not sure how to do what you're suggesting? I need to just set the filter, grab the list of values, and hit a button to transpose, copy values (need to keep my color/cell formatting) and then select specific cells each time to apply specific custom number formats to.

Comment: You realize you can right click to transpose? If the cells you are selecting are "random", there's no way to code this.

Comment: Right click to transpose does not also just paste values, it removes the formatting in the destination. Unless theres a way for me to do that! I added ``` Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        If Not rng.HasFormula Then
        rng.Formula = rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
```
And now it seems to work! I can apply my custom formatting. I'm curious if anyone has other solutions?

Comment: Right click menu also has paste values???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Replace() on the range where you're pasting values to find and replace the apostrophe with nothing.  You could do the same thing to remove the "<" also.

```vb
For Each cell In Range("YourRange")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "'", "")
Next cell
```

Comment: This seems much more elegant than the setting it's formula to a value I just tried. I need to keep the inequalities, but I bet this'll work! Lemme try, thanks!

Comment: Yep, it worked! I appreciate this forum.